# Sumar valores de una columna

Tags: php, sql

gente.. tengo esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es sumar todos los valores de la columna TOTAL y poder mostrarlos donde dice subtotal.. alguno me puede ayudar con la formula que tendria que hacer para poder mostrar eso? luego el resto de los items se calcula ya con el subtotal..

pd: los datos que figuran abajo estan escritos a mano en html, sin ninguna formula.

codigo php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte en temas relacionados con código php o sql (por tus tags) es útil que pongas el código que llevas hecho. Así podremos trabajar con ello aclarando dudas o abordando cuestiones del código.

Comment: perdon, ahi lo edite y agregué el codigo php.. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Respuesta:** Añadir una variable `$total=0` y cuando vayas consultando el total de los elementos ir sumandolo. Ej:

```
$total=0
...
$while($columna=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
     echo "<tr>";
     ...
     echo "</tr>";
     $total+=$columna['total'];
}
...
echo "</table>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<td>SubTotal</td>";
echo "<td>".$total."</td>";
echo "</table>";
```

**Sugerencia:** Añadir si existe alguna columna que cumpla la consulta

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if($count > 0){
    while($columna=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
         .....
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho.

Answer (score 1):

La fórmula que pides es la suma y la función en sql es `SUM()`

Para el subtotal, la consulta sería de este tipo.

```
SELECT
    SUM(total) as 'subtotal'
FROM factura1
```

Y da algo de tipo.

```
| subtotal |
|     1190 |
```

Posiblemente quieras hacer una variable de tipo.

```
$subtotal = "SELECT
                 SUM(total) as 'subtotal'
             FROM factura1";
```

Supongo que con lo que próximamente tendrías que lidiar sería con el tipo de dato que está en la columna "consulta".

Comment: muchas gracias!